# Is the following definition of orthonormal basis in Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, hilbert-calculus

Let $H$ Hilbert, then $\{e_n \} \subset H$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$ if
$|e_n|=1$ for every $n$,
$\langle e_n,e_m \rangle =0$ for every $m,n$ and
$\overline {\operatorname{span}(\{e_n \})}=H$.

Recall that  $\operatorname{span}(\{e_n \})$ is the space of finite linear combinations.

Now call $\infty-\operatorname{span}(\{e_n \})$ the space of  linear combinations of infinitely many elements.

Is it the same in the definition of orthonormal basis to ask that
$\infty-\operatorname{span}(\{e_n \})=H$ (i.e. like it happens for abstract Fourier series)?

Comment: You probably don't mean "infinitely many linear combinations", which would be counting the vectors. Possibly just "linear combinations of infinitely many basis vectors"? But what a combination like that means is harder to define in the first place.

Comment: Your definition of $\infty-span(\{e_n\})$ is unclear to me.

Comment: (And picky detail: $\langle e_n, e_m \rangle = 0$ for every $m \neq n$.)

Comment: Mathematicians allow non-separable Hilbert spaces.  So an orthonormal basis need not be countable.  But still, it is the same idea.  For orthonormal sets in Hilbert space, you get the closed span using convergent infinite linear combinations.  (This may not work for other types of sets, so watch out.)

Comment: Yes I meant linear combinations of infiitely many basis vectors @aschepler

Comment: The definition was taken from Brezis' book (2010) p 143 and $n$ was suspicious to me. Does he mean that $n$ lives in an uncountable set? @GEdgar

Comment: See if Brezis restricts to separable Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $\overline {\operatorname{span}(\{e_n \})}=H$ is equivalent to
$$
 {\operatorname{span}(\{e_n \})}^\perp=\{0\}. 
$$
This is enough to show that every $h\in H$,
$$
h=\sum_n\langle h,e_n\rangle\,e_n. 
$$

Comment: Yes thanks. How do you show the equivalcence?

Comment: @carlos85: If $\overline K=H$, then $K^\perp={\overline K}^\perp=H^\perp=\{0\}$.
Conversely, if $K^\perp=\{0\}$, then $\overline K=K^{\perp\perp}=\{0\}^\perp=H$.